# Sed variable expansion and \n match when trying to append some text

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I've the following template file

```
# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#



# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
#http_access allow localhost
```

I want to append some text after the line bellow using sed (this is a requirement, I can't use another tool)

```
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
```

I'm tried to use the following command:

```
sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/aTEXTTOAPPEND" test.txt
```

The result:

```
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
TEXTTOAPPEND
#
```

The old code used perl to do the job

```
perl -i -0pe 's/(#( |\t)*\n# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#( |\t)*\n)/\1\n'"$REPLACE"'\n/g' /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

I'm facing two problems:

1 - Not being able to use a varible in this append command

I tried so far:

```
$ echo $REPLACE
TEXTTOAPPEND

$ sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/a${REPLACE}" test.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown command: `B'

sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/a\${REPLACE}" test.txt
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
${REPLACE}
#
```

2 - Not being able to match the hash character after the line I want to append the text (when I add the \n the command stop matching, so, nothing is added in this case)

```
sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#/aTEXTTOAPPEND" test.txt
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
```

Expected output:

```
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
TEXTTOAPPEND
```

Can someone point what I'm missing here? For variable expansion I thought using double quotes and ${var} would do the job.

---

Update:

I was trying everything using git-bash, when trying in a real linux machine the command bellow worked:

```
echo $REPLACE
ABC

sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*/a${REPLACE}" test.txt
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
ABC
#
```

the only problem now is the 2. how to work with the \n in this case?

```
sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#.*/a${REPLACE}" test.txt
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
```

Comment: can you share the output of `file test.txt` and/or `cat -vTE test.txt`

Comment: The first command you have in 1) works (at least in GNU `sed`); I don't know how you got the error message you report. Question 2) is trickier, because `sed` processes files line-by-line, and a line (by definition) won't contain a newline character followed by other characters.

Comment: @umusuarioqualquer: run `dos2unix file.txt` and try running your `sed` command

Comment: `unknown command: 'B'` Well, I guess that the variable has multiple lines, not one, like `REPLACE=$'something\nB something'`, right?

Comment: Hi all, I did an update in the question, the problem 1 was fixed by using a real linux machine instead of git-bash, the only remain problem now is point 2, thank you for all the help until now :)

Comment: @KamilCuk right, I want to add more than 20 lines, it's a config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone point what I'm missing here?

Commands in `sed` are separated by a newline. Sed sees a newline - it assumes the command ends here. I can reproduce your `sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown command: 'B'` with simple variable that has a newline and the next line starts with `B`:

```
replace="something
B something"
sed "/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/a${replace}"
```

`sed` sees `asomething` and appends `something` to the output and newline terminates the `a` command. Then it sees `B something` and tries to parse that as a command, but `B` is invalid.

The most safest way to append content of the variable with sed is to use a temporary file with `r` command. Note, that you need a newline after `r` command after filename, because any `;` will be parsed as part of the filename! In bash, you can be smart and combine process substitution with a here string to create a temporary file descriptor*. To output current pattern space and read next line into pattern space in sed use `n` command. Like this:

```
sed '/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/{n;r'<(cat <<<"$replace")$'\n}'
```

It will append the content of `replace` after the next line after the regex. Note that after `r` there is `$'\n'` - a newline.

* Just a `<(echo "$replace")` would work too, but I somehow feel the `cat <<<"$replace"` will be better in memory consumption for big strings, I didn't check that in any way.

The following script:

```
replace="anything
can
be here!"

cat <<EOF |
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
EOF
sed '/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/{n;r'<(cat <<<"$replace")$'\n}'
```

[outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LargeBiodegradableOutliner):

```
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
anything
can
be here!

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
```

> how to work with the \n in this case?

Sed reads one line at a time. As this is very similar, I would just point to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59634679/9072753) I did just yesterday that deals with the same problem. The script in sed this case would need to buffer two lines at a time with `N` command:

```
sed '
  : restart
  N # buffer two lines
  : loop
      # match two lines
      /# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#/{
           r'<(cat <<<"$replace")'
           # print and start over
           n ; b restart
       }
       # hold, print leading line, change, remove leading line
       h ; s/\n.*// ; p ; x ; s/[^\n]*\n//
       # append next line and loop
       N
  b loop
'
```

But you can't do `rsomething` or `asomething` with `sed -z` because then records would be separated by zero, so sed reads the whole file, so `asomething` would be displayed after the whole file. Well, you can test it `sed -z '/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#.*/r'<(cat <<<$replace)` and it will just print the content of `$replace` on the end of the file.

Comment: Amazing, you did it work, thank you for all the help, I would never imagine how to do that work. Still learning about sed, but even reading sed docu was not so clear about stuff like that.

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/!b;n;r'<(cat <<<"$replace") file` might work too?

Comment: @potong yes, it should work. It's is nice, because it doesn't need the `$'\n'` on the end.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<! | sed 'N;/^# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#/!{P;D};r /dev/stdin' file
Text to be appended or a variable
$var
or both $var
!
```

Construct a here document to be appended and pipe it through to the sed invocation.
The sed invocation uses the `N`  and the `P;D` commands to open a two line window throughout the length of the file but on matching the required two lines invokes the `r` command which appends the former here document.

An alternative:

```
sed '1{x;s/^/'"$var"'/;x};N;/^# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#/!{P;D};G' file
```

But,this should work too:

```
sed 'N;/^# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE.*\n#/!{P;D};a\'"$var" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/a '\n'TEXTTOAPPEND" file-for-change |
sed "/INSERT YOUR OWN RULE/{n;s/'/#/;n;s/^'//;n;d"}
```

Second sed is for change and removing "**'**" leading symbol at start of next two lines

Or, more simple variant:

```
sed -r '/INSERT YOUR/,+1{s/(#$)/\1\nTEXTTOAPPEND/}'
```

It works with GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest way is the best, maybe this is the case?

```
sed '8aTEXTTOAPPEND' -i test.txt
```

This will add 'TEXTTOAPPEND' after 8-th string.

And automate this

```
N=$(grep -n 'INSERT YOUR OWN RULE' test.txt) # get line number
N=${N%%:*}                                   # remove all except line number
((N++))                                      # inc line number coz we got this line with #
sed "${N}aTEXTTOAPPEND" -i test.txt          # add text after $Nth line
```

Oneliner

```
N=$(grep -n 'INSERT YOUR OWN RULE' test.txt); N=${N%%:*}; ((N++)); sed "${N}aTEXTTOAPPEND" -i test.txt
```